# highcharts prepare options for POST

Tags: asp.net, json, post, highcharts

I need to send a Highcharts options object to an asp page so it can be written to a json flat file. These files are later passed to phantomjs via highcharts-convert in order to create some pdfs.

The problem however is stringifying the objects. I keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
when I try this:

```
$.post("myASP.asp", JSON.stringify(myChart.highcharts().options));
```

There is a sample POST string here http://docs.highcharts.com/#render-charts-on-the-server but I'm not sure how to achieve that with mine. When I paste their sample into my code for testing I get all kinds of unescaped double quote errors. Is that a typo on their part?

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there are curricular references in the JSON objects. As far as I remember that is not supported by the JSON serializer.

One example of this if you have an object with an array of children that refer back to the parent.

I think you can try the following:

```
{"infile":myChart.getSVG()}
```

This should get the svg representation of the chart

Comment: Yah it looks like getSVG() is the way to go. For curiosities sake I'd like to investigate a json "flattener" of sorts but svg will work if I can't figure it out.